# Deploy Azure Package from my own WPF App

Tags: azure

I am creating a little utility app for some of my Azure work and i would love to make it possible to deploy a azure package from within my tool.

I have a package that have been created from Visual studio and i can manual deploy it or deploy it from within VS 2012.

Anyone who know a guide or can tell me how i would deploy it from my own application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Everything you see as far as deployment is concerned in VS is backed by a REST API. So you could essentially write a WPF application which is a wrapper over these REST API. There're two things you would need to do:

1. **Upload Package files to blob storage**: This would be the 1st thing you would need to do. You could make use of storage client library or implement REST API for uploading package files to blob storage.
2. **Implement "Create Deployment" Service Management API function**: Take a look at the functionality here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813.aspx. Once you have uploaded the package file in blob storage (and got the blob URI), you could invoke this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no API wrapper / SDK available that covers full functionality on managing Storage Accounts, Deployments etc. yet. You can use the [Windows Azure Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) though.

In order to use this API you need to have a valid management certificate in the subscription you want to manage and sign all REST calls to the Management API with it. There should be sufficient information about how to do so in the link above.

HTH